# How to use data validation to allow the user to ONLY input an integer, otherwise it outputs an error when a decimal is inputted

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use data validation in excel that would produce an error if a user inputs a decimal value in a column (column W) AND selected the "BCD" option from another column (column V). Please see the picture below where it shows the two columns I am describing.

In the picture, I don't want the user to input 23.45 (a decimal value) because in column V they selected BCD. Rather, I would display an error message saying that an integer needs to be input.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: This question would be more appropriate for Super User, as, unless you are looking for a VBA solution, it does not involve programming. Please consider adding an excel-vba tag or moving your question.

Comment: Just did, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: You can probably add Custom Data Validation with something like `=MOD(A1,1)=0` https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249

Comment: @Slai, wouldn't it be =MOD(A1,1)<>0?

Comment: What have you tried?  What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

If I understand your question correctly (you mentioned `UDP` but shows `BCD` in your screenshot), you can try this.

Under `Data Validation`, you can use a Custom Formula like below:

```
=(V2="BCD")*(INT(W2)=W2)+(V2<>"BCD")
```

The error will only shows when `column V` has `BCD` with `column W` has decimal numbers.  And don't forget to drag it down to cover all the fields in `column W`.

Try and let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Awesome! that works perfectly :)  Thank you for the help.

Comment: the only issue that I am seeing though is that if I select "BNR" and input a decimal value (ex 3.4) in column W and then I leave that number and only change column V from "BNR" to "BCD" then that decimal stays there and does not output any error.

Comment: I know.  That is something this `Data Validation` didn't work quite well.  You can also copy paste the decimal numbers in and it wouldn't error out.  I will say probably try `Conditional Formatting` as a second layer to warn people.

Comment: Thank you, will do that.

Comment: You are very welcome.